# Delete directory and subdirectory - Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, rm

There is a folder called Trash-1000 and i want to delete it. There are some folders in it which cannot be deleted (do not even know how they were created).

Looks like: `Trash-1000\files\Trash-0\files\src\src\src\src\src\src\src\src\src\src\...` (... and so on very very deep dir).

I have tried 
`sudo rm -rf Trash-1000` and `sudo chmod -R` both give "Operation not permitted"

Any help on how to get rid of the folder is much appreciated!

Micha

Comment: Did you specify a user with e.g. `sudo chmod -R michael:michael Trash-1000`?

Answer (score 4):

```
ls -lah Trash-1000/
lsattr Trash-1000/
```

The first command will show the file and ownership permissions. If they are 000 or root:root, the root user should still be able to remove the file regardless with this command:

The `lsattr` command above, the second one, will show if there are any attributes set on the file. If you see a -i on the lsattr command, then run this command to unset that attribute:

```
chattr -i Trash-1000/
```

This will remove that immutable file attribute. What immutable does would be preventing changing and removing a file. If the file has that set on it, even the root user cannot remove the file and this is my suspicion on what might be happening if you haven't been able to remove it even as the root user (`sudo`).

Comment: lsattr and chattr say: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on Trash-1000/files

Comment: What filesystem are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supplying a permission to change TO with chmod.

Seeing as you are about to delete them, you should be safe to use

```
sudo chmod 777 -R
```

Comment: If `rm` is called with `sudo`, changing the permissions to 777 is redundant because root will always have the privilege of deleting them at this level.